# Should an implementation of the MVC design pattern in web service architecture consist of multiple components?

Tags: json, model-view-controller, architecture

A coworker and I have an academic disagreement about how MVC applies to our system.

We have a web service that returns JSON to a javascript client.

The service has controllers and models. It returns JSON via MOXy auto-parser so everything it returns is objects/lists encoded in JSON. These are then interpreted by the client.

I'm making the argument that the MVC pattern belongs entirely to the web service component- the models and controllers are there, and the view consists of the JSON that the web service returns.

He's making the argument that the MVC pattern includes both components, that the JSON returned by the web service does not constitute a view and the view is the display that the javascript renders for the user.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are both right. The MVC is nothing else as set of design patterns used to organize and separate concerns in the web development. I think that you are confused between **Client side** vs **Server side** rendering? Where do you want to generate your HTML views, on the server or the client? The traditional was Server side but tendency is to move that toward Client side.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's a matter of definition. It may turn out you are both right, but just use different MVC definitions.

To find out who is right, first locate a definition of MVC that suits you both. Let's take [Wikipedia's one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller#Components) for an example:

> A view can be any output representation of information, such as a
>   chart or a diagram
>
> A view generates new output to the user based on changes in the model.

From this point of view, your JSON output looks like an anemic view, that is later used by an actor (user or another servce) to interact back to your controller.